# AWS Network Load Balancer Redirect Port

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, amazon-elb

I am trying to deploy a Kafka cluster on AWS (using CloudFormation). My advertised listeners are (using a private DNS namespace to resolve the internal IP):

INTERNAL://kafka-${id}.local:9092
EXTERNAL://<public-ip>:9092

However, Kafka complains that two listeners cannot share the same port. The problem is I'm using a load balancer for external traffic, and I'm not sure if there's a way to redirect that traffic to a different port.

My desired configuration would be:

INTERNAL://kafka-${id}:9092
EXTERNAL://<public-ip>:19092

But the load balancer takes the incoming request and passes it to the internal IP at the same port. Ultimately I'd like to have the load balancer take connections on port 19092 and pass them to 9092, but I don't see any way to configure that.

If there are any recommendations on alternative ways to do this, I'm happy to hear them. Currently, I need services that are on other VPCs to be able to communicate with these brokers, and I'd prefer to use a load balancer to handle these requests.

Comment: Port is defined by your target group. Sadly, your description is not clear. What ports do you use on your listeners? What ports are on your targets?

Comment: @Marcin My inter-broker traffic uses port 9092, and since I can't reuse that port, it means the public port has to be something else. So assuming I want internal traffic to use port 9092 and external traffic to use port 19092, I need a way to set up a load balancer to accept traffic on 19092 and redirect it to port 9092 (since the load balancer traffic will be seen as internal as far as the broker is concerned)

Comment: NLB does not support any redirections. You can only have different ports on listener and the corresponding TGs.

Comment: Oh, I think you answered my question. So I can set a port 19092 on the listener, and this will be what the incoming traffic uses, and then set port 9092 on the target group, and this is what the internal LB to service will use?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for your help! I feel stupid for missing this. I'm still getting used to deploying things on the cloud.

Comment: No problem. If that solves your issue, I can provide an answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? If not, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this fixed this particular issue. I ran into another issue that's unrelated to AWS but I found a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The NLB does not support redirection rules in its listeners. It only has **forwarding** rules. But a listener can use different port that its targets defined by a target group. So a possible setup could be:

```
Client ---> Listener on port 19092 ---> NLB ---> Target group with port 9092
```

Comment: what should be the sg inbound rule for the target group instance?
should it allow traffic on 9092 from the VPC subnets or from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

@Marcin answered this for me. See comments for details.